# Weekly data manipulation in python pandas based on first of month

Tags: python, pandas, average, date-manipulation

I have monthly data in xls that I upsampled into weekly average. Now I need a condition/function to include previous month's last week if the 1st falls on a Monday or Tuesday and reaverage current month. I was using pandas resample().

**Sample input: Monthly Data**

```
|    Date   |   Store  |  Fruit  |  Quantity  |
|:---------:|:--------:|:-------:|:----------:|
|Jan 2021   | A-Mart   | Apple   |     70     |
|Feb 2021   | A-Mart   | Apple   |     60     |
|Mar 2021   | A-Mart   | Apple   |     90     |
|Apr 2021   | A-Mart   | Apple   |     40     |
|Jan 2021   | A-Mart   | Banana  |     40     |
|Feb 2021   | A-Mart   | Banana  |     100    |
|Mar 2021   | A-Mart   | Banana  |     80     |
|Apr 2021   | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
```

**Current Output: Weekly Data "Sunday" Averaged**

```
|    Date   |   Store  |  Fruit  |  Quantity  |
|:---------:|:--------:|:-------:|:----------:|
|03/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|10/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|17/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|24/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|31/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|03/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     15     |
|10/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     15     |
|17/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     15     |
|24/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     15     |
|07/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     22.5   |
|14/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     22.5   |
|21/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     22.5   |
|28/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     22.5   |
|04/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     10     |
|11/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     10     |
|18/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     10     |
|25/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     10     |
|03/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|10/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|17/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|24/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|31/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|03/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     25     |
|10/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     25     |
|17/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     25     |
|24/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     25     |
|07/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
|14/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
|21/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
|28/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
|04/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     5      |
|11/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     5      |
|18/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     5      |
|25/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     5      |
```

**Target Output: 1st of month on Mon-Tue add previous week into current month (Weekly Average)**

```
|    Date   |   Store  |  Fruit  |  Quantity  |
|:---------:|:--------:|:-------:|:----------:|
|03/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|10/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|17/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|24/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|31/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     14     |
|31/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     12     |
|03/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     12     |
|10/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     12     |
|17/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     12     |
|24/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     12     |
|24/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     18     |
|07/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     18     |
|14/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     18     |
|21/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     18     |
|28/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     18     |
|04/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     10     |
|11/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     10     |
|18/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     10     |
|25/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Apple   |     10     |
|03/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|10/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|17/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|24/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|31/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     8      |
|31/Jan/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
|03/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
|10/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
|17/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
|24/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     20     |
|24/Feb/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     16     |
|07/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     16     |
|14/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     16     |
|21/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     16     |
|28/Mar/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     16     |
|04/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     5      |
|11/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     5      |
|18/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     5      |
|25/Apr/21  | A-Mart   | Banana  |     5      |
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to add what you have tried in addition to what you want.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I haven't really tried anything past the point of resampling the monthly data and averaging the values. I am lost and have no idea how to do it past this point.